# Git: is there a possibility to clone an entire webapp without overwriting for end user cloning?

Tags: git

The title is not very clear, and I don't know if stackoverflow is better place to ask.

I'm working on a webapp that permits control of Domoticz (domotic software) via API.

The webapp is fully functional on a webserver. So, end user with little knowledgment of PHP can clone it and work on it. He can also write own script, they need to be in same folder of original (`/app/models`)

The webapp is open source and it is here: https://github.com/sineverba/domapi

My Webapp is also based on other libraries via composer.

So, for first installation, an user can simply `git clone` and get all stuffes. But, how manage an update?

I'm thinking of a script bash that user can launch (e.g. `sudo ./update` ) and it:

- clone in a temp folder
- move only the updated files (I want reccomend on instruction to no edit original file but extends them instead)
- delete the temp

Do you think is best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user can create their own fork of your repository using git. They can then pull from your repository (configured as a remote in their local repository) to merge in your changes into their repository. So the `git pull` command is sufficient for this. You don't need to write any script.